# JS Optimization/Performance: Comparing objects using JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, object, optimization

I'm currently building a small application is Vanilla JS (without any dependencies like lodash/jquery) and I needed to compare two objects to check for equality in keys and values. I was just wondering about how to optimize this problem.

The keys of both objects are in the same order as they are derived from the same method. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249), the fastest and most efficient way to do this is using `JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2)`.

However, in my app, if the two objects are not equal, then I loop through the two of them and perform some operations. The problem is that these operations are pretty performance heavy and run occasionally. I need to optimize my solution.

Therefore, I was wondering if `JSON.stringify` runs some sort of `for` loop internally as well. In my application, it is more likely for the two objects to be unequal. Therefore, if `JSON.stringify` also runs some sort of `for` loop, I could just remove the check and run the operations I need right away (**which will only cause a difference in the program if the two objects are unequal**) saving time and making it more optimized. If I don't do this, then I will technically be running two `for` loops for the exact same purpose when the two objects are unequal and running one `for` loop either way when the two objects are equal. If `JSON.stringify` is some sort of `for` loop internally, then I can just one `for` loop no matter if the objects are equal. Am I making sense here? Please let me know if you don't understand something. Is this check useless and should I remove it to optimize my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question touches 4 different areas:

- The implementation (and thus performance) of `JSON.stringify`
- The implementation (and thus performance) of object iteration
- The quality and performance of the JIT compiler
- The speed of memory allocation (`JSON.stringify` is a memory hog for big objects)

So it is quite clear, that there is now "Universal" answer for all JS engines and OSes.

I recommend you do checks your in code ... why?

- While right now the order of attributes might be constant, future maintenance to your codebase might change that and introduce a hard to track down bug.
- It is good practice to create an `isEqual` method for all object types you use
- It is better readable.

Ofcourse there are also disadvantages:

- Your code will become bigger (this might be linked to better readable)
- ANything else I might have forgotten.

Comment: what do you mean by "dor your checks in code"? sorry, i know that's a typo but I can't deduce exactly what you mean. So to be more clear, you recommend checking for equality first , correct?

Comment: Good catch! Fixed the typo. What I mean by "do the checks in your code" is either run a `for` loop yourself or maybe just write it out as one condition for every relevant property - this makes it much easier for the JITer to create fast code.